# On tab press move out of quotes - PHP Storm

Tags: phpstorm

I have searched for the answer to this but have came up empty handed. I want to be able to use PHP Storm the same way I do Aptana Studio where I can press tab to move the cursor out of the brackets or quotes.

So if I am writing an `if` statement and I come to the end of it

`if($x != $y|)`

where the pipe is the cursor and I press tab it then moves the cursor to the outside of the parentheses like so:

`if($x != !y)|`

Is there a setting I am missing to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not currently supported, please vote for [IDEABKL-6984](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984)

Comment: Wow that was created in 2011 something tells me it will probably not be implemented any time soon. Back to Aptana I go.